# How do I reset my counter when it gets to the end of my array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that iterates through an array on click and displays the contents of the array. When I get to the end of the array, I would like to set the counter back to the beginning. Here is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="likes">
<span class="figure">
</span>
</div>
<button type="button" id="like" >Like</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var clicks = 0; $("#like").click(function(){ clicks++; 
$('.figure').html(clicks);});
```

working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nTmu7/2/

Comment: Where is your array and "displays the contents of the array"? Now, it only sets the integer content.

Comment: `count = count % myArray.length`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the Reminder  operator (*AKA:* Modulus)  `%` to **loop** your array

```
counter = (counter + 1) % array.length;
```

Example:

```js
var array = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
var counter = 0;

$("#like").click(function(){
  $('#likes').text( array[counter] );
  counter = ++counter % array.length;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="like">LOOP ARRAY</button>
<div id="likes"></div>
```

Always good to re-read: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Comment: Why is the second option discouraged?

Comment: @AndrewB - its syntactically weird.

Comment: @wahwahwah isn't it common in many languages and widely used?

Comment: @AndrewB in any case you should preferabily use code that is obvious and readable. "Obfuscating" code can lead to tiredness and bugs.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Was simply curious because I use the short version so often, if I am doing something wrong/frowned upon its nice to know :)

Comment: @AndrewB there's no *wrong way* as long you're doing it the *right way*. There's only the more-or-less bug prone way. When you're confident use any *golfcode* you like. Just remember how many times you stopped for a second while reviewing someone's else code looking like: `v%=n?++a:!--b%a?a^1:v;` second + second = lifetime ;)

Answer (score 2):

Modulus the counter by the size of the array. I.e. I % array.length will get you back to 0. If I equals the length. I normally have an if statement.

Like

```
if(I == array.length){
    I %= array.length;
}
```

Comment: Sorry place the mod in front of the = sign

Comment: Thanks for editing my answer. I'm on my phone, and it's a pain to make post with the app.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use modulo (`%`).
Taking the modulo by length of an array guarantees that you never excced it:

```js
var ind = 0;
var val = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

$("button").on('click', function() {
  ind = (ind + 1) % val.length; // or "ind++; ind %= val.length;"
  $(this).text(val[ind]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>a</button>
```

Comment: It's always good to know the DOM Element properties, **but!** jQuery is there exactly cause it handles standard/non-standard `textContent` / `innerText` out of the box.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Oh, it is just an example :) I have updated an answer according to your clarification.